# Call javascript from XForms action

Tags: javascript, xforms, xsltforms

I am experimenting with XForms and trying to dynamically load javascript, but cannot figure it out.

I am presenting a simple example - that is just an input field and button that loads the javascript:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
   xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" >
   <head>
      <title>Hello World in XForms</title>
      <xf:model>
         <xf:instance xmlns="">
            <data>
               <firstName/>
            </data>
         </xf:instance>
      </xf:model>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var myFunction = function(){
           var name = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
           alert("Hello " + name + "!");
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <xf:label>Please enter your first name: </xf:label>
      <xf:input ref="firstName" id="firstName">         
      </xf:input>
      <br />
      <xf:trigger>
         <xf:label>Click me!</xf:label>
         <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
            <xf:load resource="javascript:myFunction()" />
         </xf:action>
      </xf:trigger>
   </body>
</html>
```

So in my script I am trying to get the value from the input box and then show an alert box with concatenated string. Currently, I get **"Hello undefined!"**

Do you have an idea how to get the value from the `firstName` `xf:input` with Javascript? 
I know how to do it with XForms only, but this is sort of a proof of concept.

On a side note - I am using XSLTForms, so the XForms runs on the client.

Another hint might be in the fact that XSLTForms transforms the `xf:input` into several nested `span` elements with a `<input type="text">` element, but that `input` element does not have a name or id.

Comment: You have to set the `id` of the input, not only the name because you are using `getElementById`. In your example: `<xf:input ref="firstName" name="firstName" id="firstName">`.

Comment: Yes, I actually set the `id` of the input. But in my trial and error attempts, I was also experimenting with `getElementByName`. I made an edit. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: What do you actually want the script to do?  Your current example could be achieved using xf:alert.  Other script-like functions may be achieved using xf:bind

Comment: I want to get the value of the `xf:input` with javascript. I know it can be achieved with XForms alone, but as I said - this is an experiment that I am currious how can that be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLTForms, there are different possibilities...

If you want to access the value of the corresponding HTML input, I would suggest `document.getElementById("firstName").xfElement.input.value`.

You could also use the node property to get the value stored in the bound node.

Don't hesitate to browse DOM with a debugger to find how to get things from XSLTForms!

--Alain

Comment: That's it! Feels nice when the answer comes from the people behind XSLTForms :) Thanks!